# How to list only product, not the attribute?

Tags: php, magento

This code list the product order, but the list is doubling configurable products, how to fix it?

Order Example:
Configurable: Car.
Simple (associate): Car Yellow.

```
$order = $this->getOrder();
$increment_id = $order->getincrement_id();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order->getincrement_id());
$ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($ordered_items as $item){
echo $item->getName();
echo number_format($item->getPrice();
}
```

This one result:
Car 10.00
Car Yellow 0.00

And i need to list only: Car 10.00.

- I have products that are just Simple, so i can not use a filter to list only configurable.

Comment: I don't know magento but inside foreach before $item->getName(); add echo('<pre>');print_r($items);echo('</pre>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading all items from the order, which includes deleted items and parent items.

You can use `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::getAllVisibleItems` to retrieve the relevant items for display:

```
$orderedItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($orderedItems as $item) { /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $item */
    echo $item->getName();
    echo number_format($item->getPrice());
}
```